# jQuery ValidationEngine and PO Box

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am currently using jQuery and the jquery ValidationEngine for a site, and it works like a charm. The issue is that I need to add the ability to check for (and dis-allow) P.O. Box addresses.  I have looked around quite extensively and have not been able to find a regex that validationengine will properly use.

I did find a regex that works in Javascript:

```
\b[p]*(ost)*\.*\s*[o|0]*(ffice)*\.*\s*b[o|0]x\b
```

but when I move that regex from a normal javascript function into the validationengine language file the regex matches on everything, even a blank entry in the text field.

the regex i added to the jquery.validationengine-en.js is as follows:

```
"notPoBox": {
    "regex": /\b[p]*(ost)*\.*\s*[o|0]*(ffice)*\.*\s*b[o|0]x\b/,
    "alertText": "* P.O. Box addresses are not allowed for shipping"
},
```

and the form element uses the following:

```
<input class="validate[custom[notPoBox]] text-input" type="text" id="ship_add1" name="ship_add2" value="" style="width:598px;" />
```

Is there any way I can get this regex to work within the validationengine framework and match properly? I have verified that the regex does indeed work on my own javascript within the page as i can create a function that will match and alert on matches as follows:

```
function poChk() {
    $("[id*='ship_add1']").blur(function() {
        var pattern = new RegExp('\\b[p]*(ost)*\\.*\\s*[o|0]*(ffice)*\\.*\\s*b[o|0]x\\b', 'i');
        if ($("[id*='ship_add1']").val().match(pattern)) {
        alert('We are unable to ship to a Post Office Box.\nPlease provide a different shipping address.');
        return false;
    }
});
```

I also checked it at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html which found matches as expected on a wide variety of entries (p o box, po box, P.O. Box, etc.)

Any help would be appreciated.

SilverTiger

Comment: FYI, `[]` isn't the same as `()` in regex. It designates a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). `[s]` is equivalent to just `s`, and I think you mean `[o0]` instead of `[o|0]`. I think you also mean `?` instead of `*` in most of those places.

Comment: unfortunately the regex is not my build, it is something i found online and had validated with javascript before trying to implement it on the validationengine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upon direction from Mads Hansen's post i hunted down a regex function "inverter" that allowed me to use my existing regex code and filter the opposite:

```
/^((?!foo).)*$/i,
```

Final code for "invreted" P.O. Box search that worked for me is as follows:

```
"notPoBox": {
    "regex": /^((?!\b[p]*(ost)*\.*\s*[o|0]*(ffice)*\.*\s*b[o|0]x\b).)*$/i,
    "alertText": "* P.O. Box addresses are not allowed for shipping"
},
```

Comment: +1 for answering your own question. Plus, the negative lookahead is probably the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a custom validation, the `regex` will test to validate that the value ***matches*** the expression and will generate a validation error if it does not.

The way you have it defined, `notPoBox` **passes** when the value ***is a***  PO Box value.

You need to check for the opposite of the match for your regex.

You could do that by using a function and returning the negated value of a regex `test()`:

```
"notPoBox": {
    "func": function (field, rules, i, options) {
                var isPoBox = /\b[p]*(ost)*\.*\s*[o|0]*(ffice)*\.*\s*b[o|0]x\b/i;
                return !isPoBox.test(field.val());
     },
     "alertText": "* P.O. Box addresses are not allowed for shipping"
},
```

[A working example in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hansenmc/gTdQN/)

Comment: i will try this and let you know. much aprpecaited for the feedback.

Comment: i gave you a thumbs up on this post, but the code would not work as is with my page, it kept saying i did not have a regex defined and it was apparently required, so the "func:" option didn't work for me. but this line of thought did help me find my solution. Thank you.